# Is is possible to store securities outside of a bank/brokerage?

Tags: banking, securities

Is is possible to store securities outside of a bank/brokerage?
It would like to hold them myself or store them with an entity with minimal exposure to the market. E.g. in the past stocks were held in the form of certificates which could exist outside of a financial institution.

Comment: You can obtain a stock certificate but that can be costly.  In addition, holding one doesn't change your exposure to the market.  Your stock 's value will fluctuate whether you possess the certificate or it's in street name.

Comment: @BobBaerker Thank you. I am thinking of the scenario where high inflation, high debt, weak FED collapse the economy and my bank isn't ready.

Comment: @Toaster and how do you expect a piece of paper to help you?

Comment: In a worst-case scenario as you seem to be concerned about, things like stock certificates, currency, even gold will be useless.  Things like non-perishable food, medicines, guns, ammunition, and the like will be much more valuable.  Watch "The Walking Dead" and you will get an idea of what's important in an apocalyptic world.

Comment: @jwh20 Lol, I see your point but I expect that economy will continue to function in some capacity.

Comment: Ahem.  It's a good time to revisit this question :-)